# Offline data cache for Cordova Mobile application

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, progressive-web-apps, offline-caching

I have a Cordova application (`Ionic3/Angular`) where I wish to add offline ***data*** cache, where I would also like to prefetch some of the data, even if the user does not go to the view that would normally invoke the request for that data.

Most caching posts I find have to do with caching `web assets` such as the actual application files, rather than data fetched via ajax. In my case, (Cordova), I already have all these, I just need to cache the data. For the asset caching, I see [toolbox](https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/sw-toolbox/blob/master/docs/api.md) mentioned a lot and being run from within a service worker.

Can [toolbox](https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/sw-toolbox/blob/master/docs/api.md) be used for this? Also, does toolbox need to be used in a service worker (worried about iOS support).

If not **toolbox**, is there something more appropriate I can use for this?

Thanks in advance for any pointers.

Comment: If you are only looking to cache ajax requests, you can manually do so by storing them the localstorage (or using `NativeStorage` plugin). You can write a javascript class like functions that all your code calls to when doing ajax request. This class can then check whether if the request is cached or not. You would have to store a special key (the url should do) so you can find the difference between all the data you have.

Comment: Thanks @kks21199, I was hoping there was some library that would do some of this stuff for "free" (ie intercept, and have caching strategoies similar to toolbox)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [ionic-http-offline-cache](https://github.com/mentatxx/ionic-http-offline-cache).
Just replace `$http` service with `httpOfflineCache`.

Comment: Thanks @kutianski, that that lib is for Ionic 1

Comment: No, but you've to create the plugins.xml if you want to use it outside ionic.

`There is no specific dependency on Ionic framework. But AngularJS and Cordova are required, and they are both available for Ionic from a box.`